# How do 'forget gates' know not to remove essential information from the Cell State in an LSTM?

Tags: neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

First off, I apologize if this isn't appropriate for stack overflow. This isn't really a code related question rather than a theory question.

This isn't completely clear to me. Say you have a massive passage that you want your LSTM to learn off of, how is it making sure it doesnt remove details from the first paragraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In BPTT algorithm, when the word did not play an important role in determining the final output, then the gradient will be small and the weight will become smaller as training is going. It is automatic as LSTM mechanism determines it.

For your concern, you may misunderstand LSTM, LSTM can solve the gradient vanishing problem because it convert the `continually multiply` to `continually plus`. Simply speaking, hi = a1*h1+a2*h2+a3*h3+...，the latter output is a function of each previous output, so the gradient is remained. You can refer to [An Empirical Exploration of Recurrent Network Architectures](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v37/jozefowicz15.pdf) for details of the gradient accumulation theory. In addition, nowadays **attention mechanism** is wide applied and is more appropriate for you need, you can see [Neural Machine Translation By Jointly Learning To Align and Translate](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.0473.pdf).

Comment: That I understand. Now, if a word/sentence appears in the first few sentences and has little significance for the next 3-4 paragraphs, it will likely be forgotten. What if it ends up being significant 5-6 paragraphs later? It won't be able to make the proper connection since it already forgot that important detail.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this paper](http://www.overcomplete.net/papers/nn2012.pdf) will be of help. It explains the backpropagation algorithm.

Also note that for LSTM's that process passages, multiple LSTM blocks are used in a sequential *and* parallel manner. And additionally, neural networks are [black boxes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93705/meaning-of-a-neural-network-as-a-black-box): we don't know how the work internally, and they make up which details are important themselves.

Comment: I see, I wasn't considering multiple LSTM blocks. So, I'd assume some blocks fill focus on details earlier on in the passage while others will focus on details that happened relatively recently?